# create chat agent using locally hosted huggingface LLM

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, huggingface, large-language-model

I'm trying to get the hang of creating chat agents with langchain using locally hosted LLMs.  I've downloaded the flan-t5-base model weights from huggingface and I have them stored locally on my ubuntu server 18.04 LTS. I've adapted the code I found in this example creating a chat agent using gpt-3.5-turbo from openai:

https://github.com/samwit/langchain-tutorials/blob/main/tools/YT_LangChain_Custom_Tools_%26_Agents.ipynb

to instead use the flan-t5-base model I have hosted locally.

I think the main difference between the example code and my code is in the example code:

```
# Set up the turbo LLM
turbo_llm = ChatOpenAI(
    temperature=0,
    model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo'
)
```

in my code:

```
model_name='google/flan-t5-base'

# save model to specified directory
original_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM\
.from_pretrained(model_name,
                 torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                cache_dir='/home/username/stuff/username_storage/LLM/weights/huggingface/hub/')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

pipe=pipeline(
"text2text-generation",
    model=original_model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_length=1000
)

local_llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)
```

I'm getting the error below when trying to run my code.  I think I might be trying to use the wrong model for this example.  I think flan-t5-base is an encoder/decoder model good for sequence to sequence, and gpt-3.5-turbo is an encoder only model.  Does anyone see what the issue may be and can you suggest how to solve it?  For example is there a better choice for opensource alternative model to gpt-3.5-turbo like say llama-2-7b-chat?  My full code and error message are below.

code:

```
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.tools import BaseTool


def meaning_of_life(input=""):
    return 'The meaning of life is 42 if rounded but is actually 42.17658'
    
    
life_tool = Tool(
    name='Meaning of Life',
    func= meaning_of_life,
    description="Useful for when you need to answer questions about the meaning of life. input should be MOL "
)


import random

def random_num(input=""):
    return random.randint(0,5)
    
    
random_tool = Tool(
    name='Random number',
    func= random_num,
    description="Useful for when you need to get a random number. input should be 'random'"
)


from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer, GenerationConfig, TrainingArguments, Trainer
import torch
import time
# import evaluate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model_name='google/flan-t5-base'

# save model to specified directory
original_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM\
.from_pretrained(model_name,
                 torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                cache_dir='/home/username/stuff/username_storage/LLM/weights/huggingface/hub/')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)


from transformers import pipeline
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline

pipe=pipeline(
"text2text-generation",
    model=original_model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_length=1000
)

local_llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)


from langchain.agents import initialize_agent

tools = [random_tool, life_tool]

# conversational agent memory
memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(
    memory_key='chat_history',
    k=3,
    return_messages=True
)


# create our agent
conversational_agent = initialize_agent(
    agent='chat-conversational-react-description',
    tools=tools,
#     llm=turbo_llm,
    llm=local_llm,
    verbose=True,
    max_iterations=3,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
    memory=memory,
    handle_parsing_errors=True
)


conversational_agent('Can you give me a random number?')
```

error:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Could not parse LLM output: Option 1:**
Observation: Invalid or incomplete response
Thought:Could not parse LLM output: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.
Observation: Invalid or incomplete response
Thought:Could not parse LLM output: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.
Observation: Invalid or incomplete response
Thought:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 1
----> 1 conversational_agent('Can you give me a random number?')

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py:310, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    308 except BaseException as e:
    309     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
--> 310     raise e
    311 run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
    312 final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
    313     inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs
    314 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py:304, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    297 run_manager = callback_manager.on_chain_start(
    298     dumpd(self),
    299     inputs,
    300     name=run_name,
    301 )
    302 try:
    303     outputs = (
--> 304         self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
    305         if new_arg_supported
    306         else self._call(inputs)
    307     )
    308 except BaseException as e:
    309     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py:1169, in AgentExecutor._call(self, inputs, run_manager)
   1167     iterations += 1
   1168     time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
-> 1169 output = self.agent.return_stopped_response(
   1170     self.early_stopping_method, intermediate_steps, **inputs
   1171 )
   1172 return self._return(output, intermediate_steps, run_manager=run_manager)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py:682, in Agent.return_stopped_response(self, early_stopping_method, intermediate_steps, **kwargs)
    680 new_inputs = {"agent_scratchpad": thoughts, "stop": self._stop}
    681 full_inputs = {**kwargs, **new_inputs}
--> 682 full_output = self.llm_chain.predict(**full_inputs)
    683 # We try to extract a final answer
    684 parsed_output = self.output_parser.parse(full_output)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py:298, in LLMChain.predict(self, callbacks, **kwargs)
    283 def predict(self, callbacks: Callbacks = None, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    284     """Format prompt with kwargs and pass to LLM.
    285 
    286     Args:
   (...)
    296             completion = llm.predict(adjective="funny")
    297     """
--> 298     return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks)[self.output_key]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py:310, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    308 except BaseException as e:
    309     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
--> 310     raise e
    311 run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
    312 final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
    313     inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs
    314 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py:304, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    297 run_manager = callback_manager.on_chain_start(
    298     dumpd(self),
    299     inputs,
    300     name=run_name,
    301 )
    302 try:
    303     outputs = (
--> 304         self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
    305         if new_arg_supported
    306         else self._call(inputs)
    307     )
    308 except BaseException as e:
    309     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py:108, in LLMChain._call(self, inputs, run_manager)
    103 def _call(
    104     self,
    105     inputs: Dict[str, Any],
    106     run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForChainRun] = None,
    107 ) -> Dict[str, str]:
--> 108     response = self.generate([inputs], run_manager=run_manager)
    109     return self.create_outputs(response)[0]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py:117, in LLMChain.generate(self, input_list, run_manager)
    111 def generate(
    112     self,
    113     input_list: List[Dict[str, Any]],
    114     run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForChainRun] = None,
    115 ) -> LLMResult:
    116     """Generate LLM result from inputs."""
--> 117     prompts, stop = self.prep_prompts(input_list, run_manager=run_manager)
    118     callbacks = run_manager.get_child() if run_manager else None
    119     if isinstance(self.llm, BaseLanguageModel):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py:179, in LLMChain.prep_prompts(self, input_list, run_manager)
    177 for inputs in input_list:
    178     selected_inputs = {k: inputs[k] for k in self.prompt.input_variables}
--> 179     prompt = self.prompt.format_prompt(**selected_inputs)
    180     _colored_text = get_colored_text(prompt.to_string(), "green")
    181     _text = "Prompt after formatting:\n" + _colored_text

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/prompts/chat.py:339, in BaseChatPromptTemplate.format_prompt(self, **kwargs)
    330 def format_prompt(self, **kwargs: Any) -> PromptValue:
    331     """
    332     Format prompt. Should return a PromptValue.
    333     Args:
   (...)
    337         PromptValue.
    338     """
--> 339     messages = self.format_messages(**kwargs)
    340     return ChatPromptValue(messages=messages)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/prompts/chat.py:588, in ChatPromptTemplate.format_messages(self, **kwargs)
    580 elif isinstance(
    581     message_template, (BaseMessagePromptTemplate, BaseChatPromptTemplate)
    582 ):
    583     rel_params = {
    584         k: v
    585         for k, v in kwargs.items()
    586         if k in message_template.input_variables
    587     }
--> 588     message = message_template.format_messages(**rel_params)
    589     result.extend(message)
    590 else:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/prompts/chat.py:99, in MessagesPlaceholder.format_messages(self, **kwargs)
     97 value = kwargs[self.variable_name]
     98 if not isinstance(value, list):
---> 99     raise ValueError(
    100         f"variable {self.variable_name} should be a list of base messages, "
    101         f"got {value}"
    102     )
    103 for v in value:
    104     if not isinstance(v, BaseMessage):

ValueError: variable agent_scratchpad should be a list of base messages, got Could not parse LLM output: Option 1:**
Observation: Invalid or incomplete response
Thought:Could not parse LLM output: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.
Observation: Invalid or incomplete response
Thought:Could not parse LLM output: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.
Observation: Invalid or incomplete response
Thought:

I now need to return a final answer based on the previous steps:
```

Comment: I am facing same issues and I think the problem is the way the LLM is getting prompted. I am using openchat3.5 but the same happens with Llama2 or any other model, which is the prompt template. It must be exactly as the model requires. Fortunately huggingface has added a function `tokenizer.apply_chat_template` but I don't know exactly how to use it in agents.